# Why does adding a photon to the crystal of a semiconductor, gives a vertical transition in the reduced zone scheme?

Tags: photons, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Why does adding a photon to the system, gives a vertical transition in the reduced zone scheme?

Considering me, it's due to the fact that a photon does not change de $k$-vector, is that correct? And why is that?

Comment: Can you elaborate?  What type of system are you considering?  Is it a solid state system composed of a crystal lattice of atoms?  Is it a photonic crystal? What do you mean by "adding" a photon to the system (is it absorbed by the crystal? - or is this a photonic crystal where you can add particle in the form of photons? Etc.)?  Etc.

Comment: It's in a semiconductor, and the photon is absorbed by the crystal, thanks in advance

Comment: Well, it isn’t perfectly vertical, but pretty close. Compare the momentum of a ~2eV photon with the edge of the Brillouin zone.

Answer (score 3):

A band structure is really a plot of energy versus momentum. Optical transitions are vertical in such a plot because the photon momentum can be neglected. The massless photon at the same kinetic energy has much less momentum than the massive electron, except in the ultra relativistic case.